# Is it true that shoots will grow only when the root system is fully established?

Tags: plant-health, soil

If you have two flower pods and one is double the size, will the plant in the double sized pod first fill out the whole pod with roots before its shoot starts growing?

Comment: That's not been my experience. Roots need sugar, from leaves to grow. The root/leaf ratio probably varies with pot size, but not to the extreme you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

No. Generally, when a seed germinates, it produces what will be its first root - often, a stem or shoot will start growing within a few days, even though there is not yet much root material. As the seedling produces more roots, the topgrowth increases too, and that will be the same in ether size of pod you're using, though the one in the smaller pod will need to be moved into something bigger before the other one.